# M-x occur-instant

Tags: emacs

I like to do something equivalent to M-x occur in  google-instant  fashion.
So as I type the regex, it will display all the matches.  This would be little different compared to M-x iseaerch-forward-regexp, because the matches will be shown in different buffer, rather than same buffer.

Is there anything equivalent?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option: [Anything](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Anything)

Provides <kbd>M-x</kbd> `anything-occur`

Answer (score 7):

Yes, check out [`ioccur`](http://mercurial.intuxication.org/hg/ioccur).

Follow the links to the latest version, download the `ioccur.el` file to a directory where you put your Emacs packages (I use `~/emacs/lisp`), and then add the following to your .emacs:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/emacs/lisp")
(require 'ioccur)
```

Comment: I found it here. http://mercurial.intuxication.org/hg/ioccur/file/c7f96148ecbc/ioccur.el.  Is there an easy way to install this in emacs directly?

Comment: Just one single problem. It complaints on Windows, while compiling.

Comment: @aartist The warning I see about `wdired-change-to-dired-mode` is just that, and can be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>C-'</kbd> (command `icicle-occur`):

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Search_Commands%2c_Overview

As with nearly everything in **Icicles**:

- You can also multiple dynamic patterns, *progressively narrowing* down the matches. You can match use substring, regexp, and fuzzy matching.
  http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Nutshell_View#ProgressiveCompletion
- You can use *negative filtering*: narrow down to a subset, then hit <kbd>C-~</kbd> to subtract that subset from the previous, larger set of matches.
  http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Nutshell_View#ChippingAway
- You can *sort* the occur hits, in various ways. That can help in terms of comparison and cycling (cycling respects the current sort order).
  http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Sorting_Candidates